# Using Oracle12C Driver with Oracle 19c Database

Tags: database-migration, oracle12c, java-11, ojdbc, oracle19c

We are working on a product migration from jboss 7 running on jdk 7 to wildfly 15 running on jdk 11 and we wanted to do this activity in phases.

So as part of the initial phase release we are first migrating our product's database from oracle 12c to oracle 19c and in the later phase we shall be migrating the product from jboss 7 (running on jdk 7) to wildfly 15 (running on jdk11).

We are aware 19c only supports ojdbc8 and higher versions but to have ojdbc8 or higher we have to migrate jdk first but we see lot of complications as part of jdk migration and jboss migrations, so we wanted to give a initial release with only the database migrated.

so would jdbc7.jar work well with oracle 19c or will there be any complication? from our initial analysis we haven't seen any feature breaks in the product till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle JDBC Driver are all backward compatible, only if you don't use new API JDBC functionnalities (you probably see as a compilation error in this case). Read this page https://www.oracle.com/fr/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html, more precisely these topics :

- Which version of JDBC drivers are supported ?
- What is the JDBC and   RDBMS interoperability matrix or the certification matrix?
- What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?
- What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDBC specifications?

You need to upgrade driver only if you want to use new functionnalities of the JDBC driver (see https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or if you want to be JDK compatible regarding the matrix compatibility shown in the Oracle FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Though, the older drivers are forward compatible, it is a best practice to have the JDBC driver from the same version as that of the Database. If you have any tighter dependency on 12 driver then you could go with that combination. Otherwise, it is better to consider the latest version.